# Are U.S. territorial claims in the Pacific compliant with UNCLOS?

Tags: international-relations, international-law

The U.S. claims territory in the Pacific as seen in the map below illustration the U.S. exclusive economic zones.

[image]

The question is: are these claims complying with the United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea? If not, what is/are the U.S. legal argument(s) for not complying with UNCLOS in regard to its territorial claims in the Pacific?

Comment: "What is/are the U.S. legal argument(s) for not complying with UNCLOS in regard to its territorial claims in the Pacific?" Well, the United States is _not_ a party to UNCLOS, _so_... it's not bound to comply under any legal argument. I'm not sure what more can be said. Perhaps you could refine your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are these claims complying with the United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea? If not, what is/are the U.S. legal argument(s) for not complying with UNCLOS in regard to its territorial claims in the Pacific?

From the looks of:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Convention_on_the_Law_of_the_Sea
- [United States and the United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_and_the_United_Nations_Convention_on_the_Law_of_the_Sea)

... the answer to your first question appears to be Yes:

> The United States accepted all but Part XI as customary international law.

Part XI establishes the [International Seabed Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Seabed_Authority) to organize, regulate and control all mineral-related activities in the international seabed area beyond the limits of national jurisdiction, and the US refused to submit to its authority.